# QFileDialog not resolving symlinks

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

```
opt = QFileDialog()
folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "choose folder", path, options=opt.ShowDirsOnly)
```

This is my code to select folders in a file browser.
By default it should be able to resolve symlinks. But i do not see this behavior.

The folder I select is /home/user/abc which is a symbolic link to /home/user/xyz.

```
>> print(f'Folder is: {folder}')
Folder is: /home/user/abc
>> print(f'Folder is: {os.path.realpath(folder)}')
Folder is: /home/user/xyz
```

Is it possible to get the actual path (/home/user/xyz) from getExistingDirectory() method without using os.path.realpath() later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in Linux, in windows the symbolic link is resolved.

QFileDialog uses a QFileSystemModel as the QTreeView model, and enables by default the resolveSymlinks property that does that job but as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#resolveSymlinks-prop) points out:

> ### resolveSymlinks : bool
>
> This property holds whether the directory model
> should resolve symbolic links
>
> **This is only relevant on Windows**.
>
> By default, this property is true.
>
> Access functions:
>
> bool  resolveSymlinks() const 
> void  setResolveSymlinks(bool enable)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>